# Does Apple approve widget-only iOS apps?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, software, widgets

Does anybody know if Apple will approve an app whose sole purpose is to provide one (or several) *today widget*(*s*)?

Somehow I have a feeling that they won't, but the fact that keyboard-only (or crappy non-keyboard emoji apps) exist makes me wonder.

Does anybody know of any similar app that has been rejected or approved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point *3.3.38* of the [iOS Developer Program License Agreement](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#agreements) states:

> **Extensions, WatchKit Extensions and Keyboard extensions:**
>
> *3.3.38* Applications that include extensions in the Application bundle must provide some functionality beyond just the extensions (e.g., help screens, additional settings), unless an Application includes a WatchKit Extension. (...)

So yes, these are allowed given that you provide some help or settings screens within the main app.

Answer (score 1):

See the topic I mentioned earlier and search on the page for 'collection of widgets' but here are a few widgets in the App Store which contain multiple widget in one app and work on the Notification Center for iOS8 or higher devices:

- [Widgets Pro](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/widgets-pro/id885138013?mt=8)
- [Wdgts](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wdgts-collection-awesome-notification/id916103272?mt=8)
- Widget
- Vidgets
- Widgets Pro
- OneWidget
- [Widgets.](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/widgets./id919787495?mt=8)
- My Widgets
- [Widgets - Calculator, Currency and Calendar](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id919143225?mt=8)

Answer (score 1):

From everything that I've learned through my career as an Apple developer the one thing they refer back to constantly is, "make your application do/provide/solve one thing really well." I believe even if the application is just a single widget, if it brings value to the user experience then it won't have a problem getting approved. When submitting an application to the app store, one of the questions that the developer has to answer is this what does this solve or how does this help the users? I believe this might be a way for situations just like this to have their chance to explain why it is a product worth selling.

Comment: This is a great take. Someone mentioned in another thread that parts of WeChat look to be a home screen, but it’s clearly a chat and communication tool with lots of extras added.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple widgets only app out there see also the major [widget topic](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1771816) at MacRumors Forum (especially the topic start post). There are also quite a few there which contain various widgets in one app.

Comment: Could you provide some examples?